# ¿Como programar Preguntar confirmar al dar clic en botón salir y cerrar sesión para Windows Form con C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, botón

Buen día,
Alguien tal vez me pueda ayudar.

Deseo que en mi formulario tenga dos opciones de salir, al dar clic en el botón X (salir) que esta por defecto en el Form. Y un botón personalizado (con el icono de la puerta y la flecha de salir o cerrar sesión) también me pregunte si deseo salir.

En si lo logre, pero cuando uso el botón personalizado me arroja el dialogo dos veces, o sea me pregunta una vez le contesto que, si deseo salir, y luego me vuelve a preguntar. Se que esto es por la programación que le di al evento Form Closing.

Estos son los códigos de programación que le di a cada botón:

Para el Botón X (por defecto del formulario) dentro del Evento FormClosing:

```
public void FormBase_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro(a) que desea salir del sistema?",
              "Consulta",
              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
              MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true; //Cancela el cerrado del formulario
        }
```

Para el botón personalizado de (el que me da problemas si esta el otro programado) cerrar/salir sesión:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro(a) que desea salir del sistema?",
              "Consulta",
              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
              MessageBoxIcon.Question)==DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit(); 
        }
    }
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que no me pregunte dos veces seleccionando esta última opción de botón?
 Anexo imagenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quitas el MessageBox del evento button1_click te lo hará una vez nada más, ya que al ejecutarse Application.Exit() esto llamará al evento FormClosing y saltará tu MessageBox. Puedes utilizar una variable DialogResult para comprobar el resultado de tu MessageBox

```
public void FormBase_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro que quiere salir del sistema?", "Consulta", 
  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dr == DialogResult.No)
        { 
           e.Cancel = true; //Cancela el cerrado del formulario
        {

    }



private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
       Application.Exit(); //sales de la aplicación y llamas al evento FormCLosig

}
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias :), la solución era simple. Solo quite el evento button1Click y me quedo como quería las dos opciones de poder cerrar más la confirmación.